# Referencing Excel sheet generates error: Variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract 2 fields from the following email.

> How would you like your name to appear on the CERTIFICATE OF PARTICIPATION? 
>   Joe Johnson (sample name)
>   Email Address Required Joe.Johnson@xxxmail.com

and the email address after "Required" which is Joe.Johnson@xxxmail.com

I want to import those two fields to Excel so I can populate a certificate and return it to the email address. Ultimately I would like to have code that would do all of the above but for the time being I would be happy just to get the following code to work.

I get a run time error on the following: `Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")`

```
Sub ExtractEmailData()
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim olItem As Object
 Dim vText As Variant
 Dim sText As String
 Dim vItem As Variant
 Dim i As Long
 Dim rCount As Long
 Dim bXStarted As Boolean
 Const strPath As String = "D:\Joe\Documents\2018 TEAMS Certificate.xlsm" 'the path of the workbook

     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Process each selected record
    rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        sText = olItem.Body
        vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
        'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
        rCount = rCount + 1

'Check each line of text in the message body
For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1

If InStr(1, vText(i), "PARTICIPATION?") > 0 Then
   vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(60))
   vItem = Split(vItem(1), Chr(62))
   xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))

End If

If InStr(1, vText(i), "Email Address Required") > 0 Then
   vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
   xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
End If

Next i
 xlWB.Save
 Next olItem
 xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
 If bXStarted Then
     xlApp.Quit
 End If
 Set xlApp = Nothing
 Set xlWB = Nothing
 Set xlSheet = Nothing
 Set olItem = Nothing
 End Sub
```

I am new to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer a simple fix, in case the problem is simple. Does "D:\Joe\Documents\2018 TEAMS Certificate.xlsm" definitely have a worksheet named "Sheet1"? If not, maybe you meant:

```
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. Yes, the 2018 TEAMS Certificate.xlsm has a sheet labeled "Sheet1". I took your advice and changed it to "Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets(1)" and get the same error.

Comment: THANK YOU. I went back and triple checked the document location - that was part of the error. Now I am getting Object doesn't support this property or method (under 'Process each selected record) on  For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

Comment: @Bert Almost every Outlook VBA question has been asked. Use the site, search. Ask a new question if you cannot figure out the reason for the error. https://www.google.ca/search?ei=gK7cW8f7MMyfzwL_g5-oBw&q=outlook+vba+object+does+not+support+this+propery+or+method+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=outlook+vba+object+does+not+support+this+propery+or+method+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5314.22542.0.23574.50.49.1.0.0.0.193.4623.46j3.49.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ODthMFravac

Comment: I am learning... been working on it for over a week now is why I reached out for help!

Comment: @Bert The question you asked appears to have due to a typo. Consider deleting the question. Now you need to research the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. If needed, even is you do not delete this typo question, you have to create a new question rather than edit this one. There is an answer posted on this question and you would invalidate that answer by changing the question.